# jQueryUI change background colour when dragging from one list to another

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI sortable, I have two lists:

- added dvds
- removed dvds

When dragging from added to removed I want the div .container background colour to change to red.

Then when dragging from removed to added I want the div .containerTwo background colour to change to red.

http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/

```
$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash"
});
$("#trash").sortable({
   connectWith: "#gallery"
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the start, stop, remove and receive methods in the sortable API docs. http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event to respond to when the list receives an item:

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/39/

```
$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".container").css("background-color", "red");
            }
});
```

And with animation:

```
$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".container").css("background-color", "green");
                    $(".container").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, "slow");
            }
});
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/43/

Comment: Nearly there mate, however I need it so when you drag the div goes green or red (depending on where your dropping), then once you drop the item in a particular div the div returns to white.

Comment: how would you get the background to change when you drag the li around rather than appearing when the item is 'dropped' into the opposite div? Got the animation working, cheers

Comment: You mean before you drop it in? To indicate you can drop it over there?

Comment: So as i click then hold the li, the container div will turn green or red, rather than it turning green / red once the li has been dropped into that area? So its only on hold of the li that the colour of the box changes?

Comment: Better version: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/47/ This will stop the animation if someone is fast enough with dragging ;) Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

try the attribute "placeholder"

```
$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more like a hover, you can use the [over](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-over) and [out](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-out) events.

See the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/61/

```
$("#gallery").sortable({
    connectWith: "#trash",
    over: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.sender.context.id != "gallery")
            $(".container").css("background-color", "green");
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        $(".container").css("background-color", "white");
    }
});
```

You can notice that i used the ui.sender attribute which is the sortable that the item comes from if moving from one sortable to another. It allows me to detect if we are on a different sortable or not in order to not change the background color if we are still in the same sortable.